# NSDrawer prevent from resizing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to prevent a NSDrawer from being resized?  I've tried setting the Min and Max content size to the same value and no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up an NSDrawer delegate which implements [drawerWillResizeContents:toSize:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDrawerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDrawerDelegate/drawerWillResizeContents:toSize:). If the method just returns [sender contentSize], the drawer's content size won't change.

If that doesn't prevent the overall drawer size from changing, your delegate may also need to implement [windowWillResize:toSize:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW9), as mentioned in the above documentation link for drawerWillResizeContents:.